# Add config transform for WebSite

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web, web-config, web-config-transform

We do have lots of legacy sites which are built with WebSite option in visual studio rather than  project. What I am trying to do now is, using TeamCity and Octopus to streamline our deployment process. For MVC sites I am able to achieve smoothly but websites are giving me hard time. First problem I am experiencing here is,

In visual studio we can add different configurations (Using configuration manager) and add transform files. With websites I am not seeing option of adding new config transform file. I am not 100% sure that this is by design or I might have some configuration disabled which is causing this behavior?

**Second question** on same line is if this is by design than why (Just curiosity)?  and how can we overcome same for different deployment scenarios to transform config files in desired manner ?

Your time and input is greatly appreciated.

[image: Below is screenshot of what I am seeing in Visual studio 2012]

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft added support for Web Publishing with Windows Azure SDK 1.8. Changes in Visual Studio 2012 and 2010 allow full support for publishing your web site projects.

You can read more about this here;
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/20/new-web-publish-updates.aspx

Also, Octopack is not supported for ASP.NET WSP's, so you're going to need to do some work arounds *sorry if you knew this already*. The information you need on how to publish and pack WSP's with Octopus can be found here

http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/124-octopack-on-a-aspnet-web-site-not-a-web-application

Comment: Thanks for your reply !! We did workaround for same. We created nuget package (using nuspec) for all legacy projects and than we gave same to octopus and octopus was able to transform same. Though we had to manually add Web.Dev.Config/Web.Release.Config and so on. So we achieved what we were looking for with little twist. Those links are useful one. Appreciate your time !!